# How to quit the C++ application in Qt QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

according to the Qt qml Type documentation

> quit()
>
> This function causes the **QQmlEngine::quit()** signal to be emitted. Within the Prototyping with qmlscene, this causes the launcher
>   application to exit; to quit a C++ application when this method is
>   called, connect the **QQmlEngine::quit()** signal to the
>   **QCoreApplication::quit()** slot.

so in order to quit the C++ application in QML i have to call this

```
 Qt.quit()
```

inside the QML files, but that only quits the QML engine i need to close the C++ application also.

here is my attempt

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QScopedPointer<NFCclass> NFC (new NFCclass);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;


    QObject::connect(engine, QQmlEngine::quit(), app,  QCoreApplication::quit()); 
// here is my attempt at connecting based from what i have understood in the documentation of signal and slots


    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("NFCclass", NFC.data());
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Thank you very much if you can help me :)

I think its because i dont know the object of QtCore thats why that line throws an error

===========================================================================
edit:

Answer given by eyllanesc works.

but when i execute Qt.quit() in on completed it does not quit. It works on the button though

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
       Qt.quit()
    }

    Button{onClicked: Qt.quit()}

}
```

Comment: `QQmlApplicationEngine`'s `quit` signal is already connected to `QCoreApplication::quit()`. You shouldn't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to learn to use the [new connection syntax in Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), in your case it is the following:

```
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::quit, &QGuiApplication::quit);
```

Update:

A workaround for the second case is to use [`Qt.callLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method)

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
         Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but i have a problem, it only works when i bind it with buttons. I have a function that when the component is completed it checks if the device ID is authorized. sure enough when the device id is not authorized it goes to qt.quit but it doesn't close the app

Comment: It works perfectly now ! Thank you good sir. May you give me a brief explanation on why this happens? I apology on not knowing this things yet.