# How to close a Qt qml application programmatically without errors?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to programmatically close a qml qt application.
I tried the method described here [How to quit the C++ application in Qt QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810358/how-to-quit-the-c-application-in-qt-qml/51810404#51810404)

```
Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
```

via qml and using

```
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::quit, &QGuiApplication::quit);
```

I also tried to close the application from c++ using QCoreApplication::quit(). And the method described in the qt documentation via signals and slots by calling the slot QGuiApplication::quit.

The problem is that the application closes with an error:

“The program has unexpectedly finished.”
“The process was ended forcefully.”

If I close the application with a standard cross, then the problem does not arise.

I suspect that the problem is in QQmlApplicationEngine. Because if I remove the line engine.load(url); then the application closes correctly.

I use QT 5.13.0 minGW and QT 5.13.0 MSVC2017 (32 and 64).

If I run in the debug, the application gives an error, but the error is absolutely not informative.
[image: debug information]

here is my application code c++:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);


    QTimer* timer=new QTimer();
    QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, &app, &QGuiApplication::quit, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    timer->start(2000);

    return app.exec();
}
```

and code qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

UPDATE:

I tried to compile Qt5.9.9 Qt5.13.0 QT5.15 and this problem occurs everywhere. But when I compiled with the Qt6.4 version, the problem disappeared and the application terminated correctly. Anyway, I'll leave the question open.

Comment: It's probably not related, but note that your QTimer will repeat. I would look at `QTimer::singleShot()`.

Comment: I tested with timer->setSingleShot(true); I get the same error :(

Comment: You usually shouldn't use `new` in a C++ application . The timer instance still exist when you exit the application. You maybe want to create that on stack, that will fix the memory leak btw.

Comment: Try with a newer Qt version (e.g. 6.4), and check "Debug Symbols" when installing Qt so that you can get more informative backtraces.

Comment: folibis . I rewrote the code as follows: QTimer timer; But i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As JarMan pointed out QTimer::singleShot() can be used to close your application. In fact, this is the example provided straight from the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html#singleShot :

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTimer::singleShot(600000, &app, SLOT(quit()));
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: In your example, a regular qt application is being created and I have no errors with it. The error appears precisely when using QML classes such as QQmlApplicationEngine.